# what is counted for itunesconnect sales number?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

At my first thought, I think it's just the total number of downloads. But I was heard from some developers that it only counts if the app is downloaded AND opened. Is it true? I cannot find any clear definition of itunesconnect's sales number online.

Comment: It's downloads - how would Apple know if you had opened an app ?

Comment: never read anything about this "AND opened" part.